# Exec Wait() is hanging forever even though I'm closing the Stdout and Stderr pipes

Tags: go

I'm trying to asynchronously read from Stdout and Stderr in realtime.

This works, but it hangs forever after execution. I'm closing the pipes so I'm not sure what its waiting on:

```
stdOutP, stdOutW := io.Pipe()
stdErrP, stdErrW := io.Pipe()

cmd := exec.Command("ping", "google.com", "-c", "10")

cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, stdOutW)
cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, stdErrW)

stdOutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdOutP)
stdErrScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdErrP)

stdOutDone := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    defer stdOutP.Close()

    for stdOutScanner.Scan() {
        // Do something with output...
        fmt.Println("From stdOut buffer: " + stdOutScanner.Text())
    }
    stdOutDone <- true
}()

stdErrDone := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    defer stdErrP.Close()

    for stdErrScanner.Scan() {
        // Do something with output...
        fmt.Println("From stdErr buffer: " + stdErrScanner.Text())
    }
    stdErrDone <- true
}()

err := cmd.Start()
<-stdOutDone
<-stdErrDone

err = cmd.Wait()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())
}
```

I even tried closing the channels both before and after the `cmd.Wait()` call

```
close(stdOutDone)
close(stdErrDone)
```

## EDIT

Per comments I got my answer

Closed writer not reader:

```
defer stdOutW.Close()
defer stdErrW.Close()
```

Then closed the channels prior to running Start()- this confuses me though. When are the channels closed? I would expect nothing to happen because I'm closing them before starting the command!

```
close(stdOutDone)
close(stdErrDone)

err := cmd.Start()
```

Comment: It is waiting for the process to exit. Or, the channel reads are blocked.

Comment: You are calling `stdOutP.Close()` after the reader which is blocked, so it will never get called (same for stderr). You also need to close the writer side of a pipe, not the reader.

Comment: @Cerise `-c` is already in use, that is not the issue

Comment: Since you are already reading all the output anyway, you could just write that yourself to stdout/stderr, forgoing the multiwriter. Then you could use `StdoutPipe`/`StderrPipe` which would be closed for you, and might be simpler depending on what else you are doing.

Comment: @JimB I want to write to the console simultaneously though, is MultiWriter not the right way to do that?

Comment: @JimB edited my post with working updates. Am I doing that right? I also still have some confusion over how/when channels get closed but maybe thats outside this question's scope.

Comment: `MultiWriter` is fine, but that means you have to close the pipes after the command completes to break the scanning loops, as opposed to the `exec.Cmd` closing the os pipes for you. The channels should be handled in a `defer` from the goroutine, but otherwise aren't sending any data so you could just use a `sync.WaitGroup`. You still have the problem of logical ordering, you want to close the pipes to break the scan loops, but you aren't closing the pipes until after you break from the loops. Close them based on the process ending, like when the process would do that itself.

Answer (score 1):

To cause the scan loops to break and the goroutines to exit, close the write side of the pipes after the command exits.  Bonus: use sync.WaitGroup to wait for goroutines to complete.

```
stdOutP, stdOutW := io.Pipe()
stdErrP, stdErrW := io.Pipe()

cmd := exec.Command("ping", "google.com", "-c", "10")

cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, stdOutW)
cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, stdErrW)

stdOutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdOutP)
stdErrScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdErrP)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for stdOutScanner.Scan() {
        // Do something with output...
        fmt.Println("From stdOut buffer: " + stdOutScanner.Text())
    }
}()

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for stdErrScanner.Scan() {
        // Do something with output...
        fmt.Println("From stdErr buffer: " + stdErrScanner.Text())
    }
}()

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
stdOutW.Close()
stdErrW.Close()
wg.Wait()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/uUib9AiDCft

Comment: The link to the code doesn't run. Also, I'm using `cmd.Start()` which is async.